# SQL Update ID field in relation

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, sql-update

I have two tables.

### Table MAIN

ID, STH, DOG, DOG_ID

### Table DOGS

ID, DOG_NAME

As I'm in process of creating "dog" dictionary **I want to assing DOGS.ID to DOG_ID in main table. Based on DOG_NAME**
In DOGS table I allredy have unique dog names and IDs

In MAIN table DOG has value that is present in DOGS table and I want to assign DOG_ID that coresponds to dog in DOGS table.

Later I will delete DOG column.

This is just exapmple of what I'm doing.

Comment: -1 And what is the question?

Comment: Can you describe what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both MS-Access and MySQL have the same `UPDATE/JOIN` syntax, so this should work for both:

```
UPDATE  MAIN
        INNER JOIN DOGS
            ON DOGS.DOG_NAME = MAIN.DOG
SET     DOG_ID = DOGS.ID;
```

**[MySQL Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cedf5/1)**

An alternative in MySQL would be:

```
UPDATE  MAIN
SET     DOG_ID = (  SELECT  ID
                    FROM    DOGS
                    WHERE   DOGS.DOG_NAME = MAIN.DOG);
```

**[MySQL Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55e67/1)**

This second query does not work in Access.